# Как отлаживать typescript и Angular проекты?

Tags: javascript, node.js, angular2, typescript, frontend

Как отлаживать TypeScript? Есть ли средства для отладки Angular проектов (например плагины для браузеров или типа того)? Чтобы можно было в нормальном виде посмотреть весь стек ошибок, увидеть какие объект существуют в текущий момент и тд.

Comment: Augury ? `debugger`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В Visual Studio Code есть неплохой дебаггер можете проставить точки остановки и пошагово выполнять программу https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/debugging